# Can't display Looker Embedded Dashboard (Embedded SSO) into an React Native Android app with webview

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview, looker

I'm developing a feature in a react native app using [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview) and Looker (Embedded SSO).

When application try to incorporate url in iframe, nothing happen. It just whiteboard is displayed.

Does anyone can help? Any help will be appreciate, thanks

below print and part of the code.

[response on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwrbT.png)

```
const Looker =()=> {
    const iframe = `<iframe style="width:100%; height:95vh; background:#A4A4A4; border:1" src="${url}"></iframe>`;
  
    const html = `<html lang="pt"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Accountfy</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"></head><body style="background:#A4A4A4">${iframe}</body></html>`
};

    return (
        <View style={{ flex:1, backgroundColor:'#FFF'}}>
            <WebView
            thirdPartyCookiesEnabled={true}
            incognito={false}
            sharedCookiesEnabled={true}
            allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
            originWhitelist={['*']}
            userAgent={userAgentRef.current}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
            startInLoadingState={true}
            scalesPageToFit={true}
            source={{html}}
            />
         </View>
    );
export default Looker;
```